# Converting SimpleCluster1D pseudo code to python

Tags: python

I refer to the dissertation written by Marcel R. Ackermann found https://d-nb.info/100345531X/34 . In the dissertation, Marcel wrote a pseudo-code for optimal 1-Dimensional K-Median algorithm. It is shown as such:

[pseudo-code for optimal K-Median](https://i.stack.imgur.com/X5JW6.png)

I tried to convert the code into python, as shown below:

```py
import math
import statistics

def cost(arr, median):
    cost = 0
    for i in range(len(arr)):
        cost = cost + abs(arr[i] - median)
    return cost

def simpleCluster1D(arr, k):
    n = len(arr)
    B = [[0] * k for i in range(n)]
    C = [[0] * k for i in range(n)]
    for i in range(k):
        c = statistics.median(arr[:i+1])
        B[i][0] = cost(arr[:i+1], c)
        C[i][0] = c
    for j in range(1, k):
        for i in range(j, n):
            B[i][j] = math.inf
            C[i][j] = []
            for t in range (j, i+1):
                c = statistics.median(arr[t:i+1])
                b = B[t-1][j-1] + cost(arr[t:i+1],c)
                if b < B[i][j]:
                    B[i][j] = b
                    tmp = C[t-1][j-1]
                    C[i][j] = [C[t-1][j-1]] + [c]

    return C[n-1][k-1]
```

However, the results i obtained is not intuitive. 
For example, when

```
arr = [50,60,70,80]
k = 2
simpleCluster1D(arr, k)
```

The result is [0,80], which is wrong. The answer should be [55,75] or [50,70]. 
I don't know where I have gone wrong.

I am wondering if anyone can help me with this conversion? I am a little confused as to the declaration of the array C - column 1 of the array contains the median, and column 2 contains a list in each array index. How do I do that?

Also, are the libraries/packages available online for R/Python (e.g flexclust in R and pyclustering in Python) already has a built-in optimal 1-D solver? I know that for d >1, it is impossible to achieve optimal result and thus heuristics are used to obtain local optimal solution. Which is why I concluded that these libraries will also solve 1-D problems with heuristics and hence answer is not deterministic. Am I right to come to that conclusion?

Comment: What do you mean by "_the results i obtained is not intuitive_"? You should provide sample input/output and expected output.

Comment: The indentation of the shown code is incorrect. Simply put a line with three backticks before and after code.

Comment: Hi Armali, thanks for your feedback. I have made the respective adjustments.

Answer (score 1):

> I don't know where I have gone wrong.

You haven't. The error is in the dissertation; the line

> 1: for i = 1,2,...,k do

has to be

> 1: for i = 1,2,...,n do

- otherwise the rows from k+1 to n of the arrays B and C aren't fully initialized.